# What do you call hypothetical inhabitants living on the Moon?

Tags: single-word-requests, demonyms

I'm writing a fiction where inhabitants live on the Moon, so I want a name for them. I know that 'venusian' means 'of or relating to the planet Venus', 'martian' means 'of or relating to the planet Mars or its hypothetical inhabitants' and so on.

But, after having observed that 'moonian' is not a word, I wonder as to whether there is a term meaning 'of or relating to the *Moon* or its hypothetical inhabitants'.

Comment: how about *aliens*? ;-)

Comment: A fun question, but surely also'opinion based'?

Comment: I like mooners... Hmm, maybe not.

Comment: I think it depends on the context. Is it the 'official name' of the people (Lunarians might fit this), a derogatory nickname given by the people (Moonies perhaps), or a nickname given by the Moon-dwellers to describe themselves, which will make them sound good (so perhaps Moonwalkers)?

Comment: Sun moon myungs?

Comment: There cannot be a right answer to this question. It's purely subjective, besides the story is fictional and hence the name for the inhabitants can be too. JK Rowland leads the way, and so did Tolkien.  I doubt even the word, Smurfs existed before the cartoon was created, but it caught on! :)

Comment: Perhaps *lunatics* or *loonies* for short. What? Those are already taken? Maybe *moonmen*, assuming that there is only one gender.

Comment: Or you can do it by dropping a syllable from "Luna", making Loon(s).

Comment: @Mari-LouA makes a good point - almost every suggestion here already has some sort of meaning, that lunar inhabitants might not want to associate themselves with.  The answer, should an author come up with something good, might come out of nowhere - for example, to borrow the Japanese suffix for "person of ___", we could end up with "moonjin" or "lunajin" (like bib's suggestion of "moonmen" but not male-oriented).

Comment: There's nothing nypothetical about the Mooninites.

Comment: They call themselves [the mooninites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mooninites).

Comment: While your questions are interesting, they'd be better with inclusion of your research which should show the words that are used to relate to the moon.  Please include your research in your questions! :-)

Comment: Are these inhabitants native, or colonists?

Comment: @user867, native.

Comment: @bib loonies is a term used by Heinlein among others (I think PKD also used it at times), as slang for people living on the moon.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, we called their place Moon, and they called themselves Mooninites? sounds unlikely.

Answer (score 75):

My choice would be *Lunarian*—employing the same Latin roots as *Martian* and *Venerian*, using the same way to build the word.

It is actually already existing term as per Marriam-Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lunarian).

Comment: I'd go for Lunarian too - only other ones I can think of that don't carry connotations of literal madness are Loonling (as in Earthling) or Moonling, but they're both a bit awkward.

Comment: Speaking as an SF reader, I think *Lunarian* is a common choice, with *Selenite* being roughly as common.

Comment: My first answer would have been lunarian too.

Comment: Isaac Asimov used the word "Lunarian" in "The Gods Themselves" 1972.

Comment: +1 ... I wasn't familiar with the Latin word *lunaris*.

Comment: +1 A beautiful word that Lunarian. I've got a friend who always talks about her dog Luna. I know what I'm gonna call her from now on.

Comment: The science fiction show [*Planetes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetes) (1999) used *Lunarian.*

Answer (score 36):

H.G.Wells, in *[The First Men In The Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men_in_the_Moon)*, referred to the inhabitants of the moon as *selenites*, but the name doesn't seem to have caught on. The only definition I can find for the word in a dictionary refers to a kind of gypsum.

Comment: Interestingly, french and spanish exclusively use *sélénites* and *selenitas*, respectively. Possibly because the word is several centuries old in those languages.

Comment: *Selenite* has caught on among SF writers. Between it and *Lunarian* I don't think either is strongly dominant. [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lunarians%2CSelenites&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) have the two about on par (the singular *Selenite* is dominant but that seems to be due to the chemical).

Comment: It all depends on whether you want to use the Latin or Greek pantheon. Luna is Latin/Roman, which is the standard for naming Solar System objects to date. Selene is Greek, and yes, selenium has the same origin; the element was named because it had similar properties to the previously-discovered tellurium (for Tellus - Earth).

Comment: Jules Verne also used this term in "From Earth to the Moon" and "Around the Moon". Thanks for making me remember how awesome those books are!

Comment: I've also encountered the term in Georges Méliès' *Trip to the Moon* (1902), though since the word doesn't appear on screen I don't know if it was applied to those characters at the time.

Answer (score 17):

via the Latin ***Luna***, I suggest **Lunans**

[Lunans (Luna: Earth II)](http://althistory.wikia.com/wiki/Lunans_%28Luna%3a_Earth_II%29)

[Loonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Is_a_Harsh_Mistress) (from the book *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* by Heinlein) - however being loony is considered a little crazy

*Lunar* is the adjective: "The Lunar inhabitants", but [lunatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunatic) is an informal term referring to the mentally ill

Lunan will be more readily understandable by anyone not Greek than their Selenite and rolls off the tongue better than Lunarian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lunarian) in my opinion :)

[Moonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonie_%28nickname%29) is a pejorative used for the followers of the [Unification Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_Church)

Comment: +1 for loonies, Heinlein did use it as a pun in the book as well if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Honestly if I were writing about a fictional people that lived on the moon I would take a different approach. What would they call their home? What would they think of the blue giant "moon" hanging in the sky above their planet? If they did not come from the earth then surely they would not call their home planet the moon... Will they have water and grow plants? Technology enough to see the lush planet they cannot reach? I would think they would be green with envy and it would be the focus of their religion and most of their stories. They might speculate about the man in the moon just as we do, and strive for ways to get there. It would likely be considered a utopian planet that could save them from their desolation. Their heaven perhaps. I would choose a name for my home planet in that context I think. Not an answer - just a suggestion. Be creative and make it your own.

Comment: That's an approach with pedigree, e.g. (Out of the Silent Planet)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Silent_Planet] by CS Lewis, however some term may be needed when introducing these beings, before their own name is known to the reader.

Comment: Earth would not appear to orbit - it would have phases, but remain stationary in the sky.

Comment: I _LOVE_ this answer! It shows up the egocentric way we so automatically think about things. We need to be constantly reminded not to be that way. This is thoughtful, creative, beautiful, and RIGHT. Thanks, John!

Comment: Thanks John! @Random even better! It would always be there, waxing and waning in the sky above them, reminding them of what they don't have. Imagine the religions that would spring forth from that! I could see them performing elaborate rituals. It seems they should be able to make out elements of weather on the earth as well, a swirling atmosphere they lack on their home planet. How they would speculate! I wonder if solar storms that create such vivid light shows on earth might be visible to them through a telescope? and what of those on the dark side? Only rumors of it would reach them.

Answer (score 6):

*Of or related to the moon* is ***lunar***. Perhaps the word ***lunatic*** expresses the idea of the moon's inhabitants.

There was an LDS [Mormon] belief that the moon was inhabited, but they simply refer to “the inhabitants of the moon”. [At least one commentator](http://www.mrm.org/moon-men), however, calls them ***moon-men***.

Comment: I find that 1950's sexist

Comment: So you said earlier. I make no comment and merely present the research; there's probably a question here about the use of the word "man" to mean "person".

Comment: being a mormon, i can assure you that there is no such belief at the moment. I can't really tell how widespread that belief was back in the days, but i'm quite sure it was never official doctrine.

Comment: @kutschkem Thanks: happy to clarify in the answer that it's not current now.

Comment: @AndrewLeach np ;-)

Answer (score 5):

What about deriving the name from some other property of the Moon?

- The Moon is in High Earth Orbit -> a **heo, two heos** (almost similar to the greek word for Sun, helios)
- **Fortnighters** - the night on the Moon lasts for, uh, a fortnight :-)
- **Regos**, that regolith sticks to just anything
- **Copernicans**, if they all live in or originate from the same crater
- **Neils (and Buzzes)**, in honor of Mr. Armstrong & Mr. Aldrin
- **Farsiders**, if they hid from humans there until discovered

Comment: That's an interesting idea, it's more similar to what you might expect would arise as slang.  "Oh those crazy fortnighters" or "Damn dirty Regos!"

Comment: I like Regos, as it ties into the structure of the moon, and could be a pejorative from an Earther.

Answer (score 4):

No term currently exists, because we haven't really needed one: the Moon has no inhabitants. Different authors who wrote about people on the Moon tended to coin their own terms, but none have really caught on as standard yet.

The end result is that you get to coin your own term too. If you want to derive from Latin, I'd suggest "Lunans." If you want the word to have Germanic roots instead, "Moonfolk" should work.

I think the Latin derivation has a somewhat more scientific feel, while the Germanic derivation sounds more mythic. Either way, you should pick whatever feels best for your work.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is not uncommon to refer to Earth's inhabitants [Earthlings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Earthlings), the obvious generalization would be **Moonlings**. Unfortunately that also [seems](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moonling) to be synonymous to lunatic in the meaning of simpleton...

Comment: In a similar spirit, one could generalize [Terrans](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/terrans) to **Lunans**, but that just doesn't sound so good to me...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say "Moonwalker". It does have some different meanings [colloquially](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moonwalker) and it's the name of a Michael Jackson [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095655/) so it might not be that original.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the theonymous tradition one could call them ***Selenians*** after the Greek moon goddess.

And I don't know how ***moonling*** came about to mean lunatic.

According to the dictionaries ***mooner*** has been misappropriated in a similar manner. However I don't see a problem with ***Luner*** as a general term for your hypothetical moonwalkers.

**Edit**: In fact according to OED ***Selenian*** is extant and means just that - *of or pertaining to the moon* considered **as a world**.

Eg. ...*we should not select the Moon as a habitation ; and the Selenians, if there be any, must be a peculiar race* (courtesy - FumbleFingers)

Comment: Sounds good to me. OED **selenian** *- of or pertaining to the moon considered **as a world***. I know **tellurian** *(an inhabitant of the earth)* is Latin, not Greek, but I think that's the pairing I'd go for.

Comment: thanks for that - it was purely a calculated neologistic exercise on my part - may I copy this information to the answer?

Comment: By all means copy whatever you want from my comments. Here's a (rather old) specific instance [*...we should not select the Moon as a habitation ; and the **Selenians**, if there be any, must be a peculiar race*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+the+Selenians%2C+if+there+be+any%2C+must+be+a+peculiar+race%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to consider Mooners  or Moonsters :)

Comment: 'Moonsters' is very nice, congratulations!

Comment: Moonsters... sounds like cows in gangs :-)

Comment: that what happens maybe when the moonsters moon haha

Answer (score 1):

In Robert Heinlein's "The Moon is a Harsh Mistress", the inhabitants, who are almost all transported convicts or descendents of such, all refer to themselves as "Loonies".  In much the same way, I imagine, that Yankees took that pejorative on as a badge of honor, to spite their enemies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you were looking for a colloquial term/insult/slang for these people I'd go for something like *Luny*, *Looney* or *Luney*. Base on on the Latin origin of *Moon* and the fact that you might end up insane living on such a barren, desolate place.

Answer (score 0):

I think if there were people living on the moon that we would call them whatever they wanted us to call them.

I think if you are writing the book then your "Moon" people need to have a name for it.  The fact is they would have a name for the place they called home.  They might not have a clue what Moon/Lunar is.

Name the moon, name your people on the moon, and let them be introduced.  If an advanced civilization came to us and lived on the moon we might refer to them as Martians at first but then it would be **whatevertheywantustocallthem**.

Comment: Huh, I was under the impression that we English-speakers historically ignore what the people of a given place call themselves and come up with a name based on our traditional way of referring to the place they're from.

Comment: ... not only us English speakers, but all speakers of anything anywhere ever. We don't call people "les français", "die Deutschen", "belorusy" or "ukraintsy", and they don't call us "Englishmen", "Scots" or "Irish".

Comment: Yes we English speakers do ignore what people call themselves but something tells me if it were an alien race we would probably use their name or a nickname of their name.

Answer (score 0):

Moonman or Moonwoman is the best word to describe

Comment: Please explain the reasons for your choice to help the OP arrive at his conclusions.

Comment: because they live in the place called Moon. simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

They can be called any of **Moonian**/ **Lunarian**/ **Moonarchs**.

Answer (score -1):

Lunadens

Lunar + Denizens = Lunadens

Comment: Shouldn't it be *lunazens*, then?

Comment: That would work too.  "Lou-Na-Dens" or "Luna-zens".