# What do you call someone from the Sun?

Tags: single-word-requests, demonyms

Is there a proper word that can be used to refer to someone (some living/sentient entity) that originates from the Sun? I'm guessing "solar" would not be the proper word for this.

Comment: Well... I doubt this has been asked before.

Comment: You can call them anything you want as there is no established word, as there is no living on the Sun.

Comment: I suggest "tan".

Comment: @Dan - _sunburned_ might be even better :^) We could even use a hyphen.

Comment: In the movie [Escape from Planet Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0765446/), the big red alien with one eye is from the sun...  I'll have to pay attention the next time the kids watch it to see if they ever refer to her race.

Comment: You might consider *Sol* as she is the goddess of the sun in Norse mythology (also the Latin name for the Sun) and she is depicted as the embodiment of the sun. The game *Smite* has the character *Sol* and she looks like this: http://hzweb.hi-rezgame.net/smite-web/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Sol_Blog.jpg

Comment: Well, "smokin'" would probably be appropriate, but I'd probably refer to a sun god such a Ra or Sol.

Comment: I'd call him "Burnie".

Comment: Similar to this question: [What do you call hypothetical inhabitants living on the Moon?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127824/what-do-you-call-hypothetical-inhabitants-living-on-the-moon)

Comment: I'd call them "Ray".

Comment: "Hottie," "Spot," "Bright Eyes," "Salamander Sam," "Juliet," "Hyperionian," ... the possibilities are endless.

Comment: "Squints" would be apropo.

Comment: Assuming it was male, I'd call him "sonny".

Comment: A *sol man*. You're welcome.

Comment: When I first saw the title of the question I thought "a reporter" ... thinking you meant a newspaper called *The Sun*.

Comment: There's always "Red Hot Momma".

Comment: What kind of being can live or come from a permanent hydogen bomb or whatever kind of bomb the sun is?

Comment: @rogermue: [Mushroom people](http://www.classichorrorcampaign.com/tag/attack-of-the-mushroom-people/), probably.

Comment: The reason why we don't have a commonly accepted word for a person who comes from a star, is that life as we know it cannot possibly come from or survive near the surface of a star, any more that life can spontaneously form in a near vacuum.  In my opinion sci-fi should be closely based on reality and actual science.

Comment: "Dead" isn't going to cut it, "lifeless" seems more appropriate for something broken down to it's component atoms. And even the atoms are going to fuse.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you mean from the solar system, or in all seriousness from the sun, which has not even a solid surface?

Comment: In all seriousness from the sun, which has not even a solid surface. That a problem, officer?

Comment: I see the fun police have arrived.

Comment: The question is wrongly closed as opinion-based. The question is a word request, not a word invention request. Standard desk references are not helpful because the concept is rare, but an Ngram Viewer search of the suggestions given so far eliminates: *solarite*, *solarling*, *sunling* (not found), *solan*, *soltan*, *solian*, *helian* (found but not used to describe sun-based life forms). On its face, *starchild* is too broad. According to Ngram Viewer, both *solarian* and *sunborn* are in actual use in literature with the desired meaning.

Comment: Obviously a *Sol brother*.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would use **Solarian** which appears to be the latin demonym for denizens of the sun as pointed out in the comments. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Sun)

It also follows nicely in the footsteps of Martian, Venusian, and Jovian, which are the most common terms for the hypothetical inhabitants of Mars, Venus, and Jupiter respectively.

As for the usage in science fiction as pointed out in the comments, the examples I located were not used in the literal sense.  This makes sense, as most biological processes would find the surface of the sun to be somewhat less than ideal.

Comment: It's apparently pretty well used in science fiction literature: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Solarian

Comment: Moonian or Lunarian for moon? I am curious. +1)

Comment: If I were being especially droll, I might have said 'burnt' or 'no longer living'.

Comment: "Solarian" is supported by Wikipedia's [list of astronomical demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Sun), as is ["Lunarian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Moons) for the moon.  I'm not sure where the actual source is coming from though. @Rathony

Comment: @CarlKevinson I didn't put my comment seriously. I think Sonian, Moonian also sound fine.

Comment: @Rathony, I didn't mean to call you out or anything, I just wanted to give you a heads up that "Lunarian" had some support since you were curious.

Comment: AFAIK inhabitants of moon are called "selenites"

Comment: @Angelo Suddenly, the name Adam Selene makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: If you want to use "Solarian", make sure there is no confusion with Isaac Asimov's Solarians.  "Solaria was a fictional human-inhabited planet in Isaac Asimov's Foundation and Robot series. It features mainly in The Naked Sun, to a lesser extent in some later novels."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaria

Comment: I would use Selenian for an inhabitant of the Moon, but I think Selenite is well-attested (I believe it was used by H.G. Wells in *The First Men in the Moon*.)

Comment: *Lunarian* is common in sci-fi, as is the nickname "Loonie" or "Loony".

Comment: If we refer to the sun as Sol, you could use the term **Solarian** to refer to anyone from the Sol **system**, including Martians, Terrans, Jupiteranians, etc, whereas someone from the **sun itself** might be more properly called **Solan**

Answer (score 33):

Next to "Solarian," you might want to consider [***Helian***](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2947&context=wordways).

> ***HELIAN***
>
> from Greek *helios* (Sun) + suffix -*ian*
>
> A learned synonym for the term solarian - it is derived from the
> higher-status Greek, not from the lower-status Latin. The term is
> indicative of its user's erudition. [Digital Commons @ Butler University](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2947&context=wordways)
>
> heliacal: relating to or near the sun [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heliacal)
>
> *So what should you call someone from the earth? Tellus was the goddess of the earth, which gives us Tellurian (the preferred choice of E.E. "Doc" Smith). The Greek counterpart is Ge or Gaea, from which we get words like geology and perigee. A person living on Gaea would be a Gaean.*
>
> *"Terra" (and consequently "Terran" and "terrestrial") is seen a lot in SciFi, but it's no more a proper name than "earth" is. "Terra" is simply the Latin word for "dirt" or "land." It's not the name of a god or goddess, so it doesn't follow the rule for the names of the other planets.*
>
> *"Earthling" is awfully retro and "Earthian" is just beneath contempt.*
>
> *Unlike the earth, the sun **does** have a name: Sol (with the Greek equivalent being Helios). So an inhabitant of the sun would be a Solarian or Helian.* [io9.com](http://io9.com/what-do-you-call-an-alien-from-uranus-728804752)

Another possibility, by analogy with H. G. Wells' "Selenite," is [***Solarite***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Ob-mbLt249YC&pg=PA114&dq=%22solarite%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBDgKahUKEwiYvpTI64nJAhXDfRoKHZO2BVY#v=onepage&q=%22solarite%22&f=false).

Comment: Greek is actually my native language, but I didn't even think of "Helian" , mainly because there is no analog of the word "Helian" in greek. But yeah,  it doesn't sound bad.

Comment: *Elian* recommends *Helian*, a word just one character removed from his name?  I sense a hidden motive.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Maybe he dropped the *H* when he emigrated to Earth so his origins would be less obvious....

Comment: @Erik His vile Solarian machinations are entirely transparent to me.

Comment: Be cautious, as 'hellian' could be easily confused with 'hellion' (a rowdy, mischievous person).

Comment: I think your source is wrong about this being unlike the earth. The earth also has a name (or actually, three of them: the native English "Earth," the Latin-based "Terra," and the Greek-based "Gaea/Gea/Gaia").

Comment: @sumelic Hi Sumelic. I just edited my answer to make things clearer about that particular point. Hope this will help...

Comment: There are two problems with the source you now cite. First, it invents a rule that the word "Earth/Terra" cannot be a proper name because it is derived from a common noun. But in fact, "Earth" is no different from terms like "Sun/Sol/Helios" and "Moon/Luna/Selene": all of these names of deities were derived from common nouns for the astronomical objects. "Sol" just means "sun" in Latin: it is used as a common noun as well as a proper noun, and it can refer to the physical body, not just to the god who personifies it. [...]

Comment: The second problem is that, if we can trust Wikipedia, [*Terra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_(mythology)) was in fact used in practice in Latin to refer to the earth goddess. There is reference to a supposed distinction there between *TELLVS* as the name of the goddess and *TERRA* as the name of her respective element, but the actual examples of usage do not all respect this distinction (as discussed on the article's [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Terra_(mythology))).

Comment: In greek, there is the word "Γήινος" which is a direct translation of "Gaean", and is very commonly used in all sorts of contexts.

Answer (score 11):

I think Solarling or Sunling would be interesting, seeing as we are called "Earthlings". It'd be a nice name for a race a bit on the "cuddly" or more "familiar" side, though, as the name gives the connotation of that- which I doubt is what you are going for.

Comment: I like "Sunling" a lot.

Comment: "Starling" would follow that same pattern and be quite endearing. Or maybe it would be what *Solarians* call their sweethearts instead of *darling*.

Comment: Except "starling" is already a name for several bird species, so that would just cause confusion.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman True, but I'm sure context would eliminate confusion. We've managed to cope for years with the legacy of Columbus's faux pas with *Indians* (American Indians vs Indian Americans, Native Americans vs American Natives, etc.). I assume the differences between a being whose native habitat is the sun would be distinct enough from a common bird that confusion would be minimal even without context. Similarly if *Starling* was used as a being from the sun their young could be called *starlets*. That term is overloaded too but with a dash of context the subject should be clear IMO.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman `:-D` "THE STARLINGS ARE COMING!" probably doesn't convey the sense of drama that the asker is looking for

Comment: Wow, I guess I caused quite a ruckus with this one, hahaha.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, there is precedent, e.g. Buffalo buffalo :) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo .

Answer (score 2):

*starchild* or *children of the sun* could be for what you are looking for. It is a fact that our sun is a star by its astronomical definition.

An alternative could be found in the lore of the SF show Andromeda. As a avatar of the suns, Trance Gemini was a *sun-born* lightbringer, a immortal humanoid form of a star that co-exist in the common spacetime.

So, *starchild* or *sun-born* / *solar-born* are the closest definitions from my point of view.